# Pythonの3次元配列で指定したある組み合わせの配列を削除させたい

Tags: python, python3, numpy, array

Pythonの3次元のndarray配列にて、下記のように例えば`[[0 1][2 3]]`の逆の組み合わせである`[[2 3][0 1]]`を削除させたいです。

```py
import numpy as np


arr1 = np.array([[[0, 1], [2, 3]],
                 [[4, 5], [6, 7]],
                 [[2, 3], [0, 1]],
                 [[2, 3], [4, 5]],
                 [[6, 7], [4, 5]],])

arr2 = np.array([[[0, 1], [2, 3]],
                 [[4, 5], [6, 7]],
                 [[2, 3], [4, 5]],])
```

なかなか上手くいっていないのでご教授いただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array(
    [[[0, 1], [2, 3]],
     [[4, 5], [6, 7]],
     [[2, 3], [0, 1]],
     [[2, 3], [4, 5]],
     [[6, 7], [4, 5]]])

_, idx = np.unique(np.sort(arr1, axis=1), axis=0, return_index=True)
arr2 = arr1[np.sort(idx)]

print(arr2)

# [[[0 1]
#   [2 3]]
# 
#  [[4 5]
#   [6 7]]
# 
#  [[2 3]
#   [4 5]]]
```